# Removing index.php from Codeigniter on OS X 10.9.4

Tags: php, macos, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm trying to set up my local development environment on a new Mac. It's the first one I've got and I'm not really sure about different stuff.

I've set up most of the things correctly and now I can access my websites like this:

localhost/~carlo/website.com/

In the case of a Codeigniter I have to put the index.php at the end.

The .htaccess I normally use is like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /~carlo/website.com/


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|cache|captcha|fonts|forum|media|img|min|css|js|scripts|images|uploads|docs|robots.       txt|sitemap.xml|sitemap|public|tools|wpblog|assets|xd_receiver.htm)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

But it's not enough.

I added this to /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/carlo/public_html" ServerName "localhost" ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-error_log" CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common

DocumentRoot "/Users/carlo/public_html/website.com" ServerName tobecontinuedcomic.com AllowOverride All Options +FollowSymLinks Order allow,deny Allow from All
```

But still nothing. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `RewriteCond` is incorrect - I'm guessing you need this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(index\.php|cache|captcha|fonts|forum|media|img|min|css|js|scripts|images|uploads|docs|robots.txt|sitemap.xml|sitemap|public|tools|wpblog|assets|xd_receiver.htm)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: no, this didn't solve the issue.
Looking at the apache logs I receive this error: Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden: